# Cards in Bootstrap 5 - getting equal height and equal width regardless of content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'd like our cards to consider of a header with a logo image, a body with title and other information, and then footer with a more info button.  The images are logos and vary in size.  Most are stored at 300px wide and whatever height.  If I specify a height with width auto for the image, the body height fluctuates.  What I'd like is a logo image of varying height in a card-header, a card-body that has the data and card-footer that is the same height and horizontally aligned across the rows.  Large displays will have 4 cards across, medium 3 and so on.

```
<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 pb-5 d-flex align-items-stretch'>
  <div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100'>
      <img class='img-fluid mx-auto d-block' src='logo'/>
    </div>
    <div class='card-body d-flex flex-column'>
      <h3 class='card-title'>[title]</h3>
      <h6 class='card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted'>[sub title]</h6>
    </div>
    <div class='card-footer d-flex flex-column'>
      <a class='btn btn-sm align-items-center justify-content-center px-1 px-md-2' href='[href]'>View Profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've been reading SO and other guides to equal height cards and just can't come up with the magic combo to get everything to line up horizontally (i.e. if card #1 has an image that scales to 100px high, and card #2 scales to 50px - both should be vertically aligned in the header and the card-body text should start at the same height.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated as I feel I'm just spinning wheels now looking for that magic combination.

Comment: Please provide a snippet which shows the problem. It's easy to build a demo using the editor and CDN links.